# Process finished with exit code -805306369 (0xCFFFFFFF)

Tags: python, pycharm, python-turtle

When I ran the following code in PyCharm:

```
import turtle
for i in range(10):
     turtle.forward(15)
     turtle.penup()
     turtle.forward(5)
     turtle.pendown()
     import time
     time.sleep(40)
```

It said:

> Process finished with exit code -805306369 (0xCFFFFFFF)

Do you know what that means?

Comment: Need to include more of the stack trace.

Comment: Have you set up an area for Turtle to draw within?

Comment: Yes! I have tried that